# Speed Test for Buffer Alignment: IBM's PowerPC results vs. my CPU

Tags: c++, cpu-architecture, memory-alignment, microbenchmark

I was doing some research to find out the reason why data alignment on specific byte boundaries (4-byte, 8-byte, etc. dependent on the hardware) affects the computing performance. I came across this example by IBM: https://developer.ibm.com/articles/pa-dalign/

The test cases were not included, so I have written a small C++ script for the 8-byte access "granularity" (in IBM's terms) case to conduct the test (it is Listing 4 in the IBM webpage link that I have shared):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

void Munge64( void *data, uint32_t size ) {
    double *data64 = (double*) data;
    double *data64End = data64 + (size >> 3); /* Divide size by 8. */
    uint8_t *data8 = (uint8_t*) data64End;
    uint8_t *data8End = data8 + (size & 0x00000007); /* Strip upper 29 bits. */
    
    while( data64 != data64End ) {
        *data64++ = -*data64;
    }
    while( data8 != data8End ) {
        *data8++ = -*data8;
    }
}

int main() {
    const uint32_t bufferSize = 125000 ; // 125000*(8-bytes) = 1 MB

    uint64_t Buffer[bufferSize];
    auto start_time_aligned = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    Munge64(Buffer, bufferSize*8);
    auto end_time_aligned = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    // Calculate the duration for aligned case
    auto duration_aligned = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end_time_aligned - start_time_aligned);
    std::cout << "Aligned buffer execution time: " << duration_aligned.count() << " microseconds" << std::endl;


   
    auto start_time_unaligned = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    Munge64(Buffer+4, bufferSize*8); // +4 to make the buffer access unaligned
    auto end_time_unaligned = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    // Calculate the duration for unaligned case
    auto duration_unaligned = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end_time_unaligned - start_time_unaligned);
    std::cout << "Unaligned buffer execution time: " << duration_unaligned.count() << " microseconds" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

As it can be seen in the C++ code above, the first while loop takes care of the 64-bit chunks whereas the second while loop takes care of the 8-bit chunks (in case `size` is not a multiple of 8-bytes).

In the webpage of IBM, it says that the test was conducted with 10 MB buffer size and it also says that the unaligned case is approximately 4,610% (!) slower. However, in my program, I cannot even go up beyond 1 MB since it gives segmentation fault (there may be problems in the while loops assigning the pointers). In my test, I have used 1 MB of buffer and used the first access address as `Buffer+4`. The results I am getting are nowhere similar to those of IBM webpage. Firstly, unaligned access and aligned access give very similar results with aligned access averaged as `~155 ms` and unaligned access as `~147 ms`.

An important side note is that the IBM test uses Powerbook G4 PC which is rather old (production stopped in 2006).

My question is: Is my test totally wrong or the processors have changed so much that the unaligned and aligned accesses give similar results? For instance, is my unaligned access approach true when I use the starting address as `Buffer+4`? Also, why do I get Segmentation Fault when I try to use 10 MB buffer?

Comment: how did you compile?

Comment: _"Also, why do I get Segmentation Fault when I try to use 10 MB buffer?"_ Because you are allocating the buffer on the stack.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Using gcc 13.2.0 in Windows.

Comment: did you turn on optimizations? What compiler flags were used?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai No, I have not turned on any optimizations. I have compiled as default (-O0 as far as I know). I have not given any specific compiler flags.

Comment: measuring execution time of a debug build is almost meaningless. C++ can be arbitrarily slow when no optimizations are applied

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Should I turn on a couple of compiler flags to get meaningful results? What I wonder the most is whether my unaligned access approach is true or not.

Comment: The PowerPC chips were much more sensitive to alignment than the processor you are using now.

Comment: if you want to compare to numbers in the article you should use the same flags they are using.

Comment: Unrelated: `(size >> 3); /* Divide size by 8. */` should be `size / 8;`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai The problem is that there is no compiling information in the article, not even the test script.

Comment: "Should I turn on a couple of compiler flags to get meaningful results?" - Yes, absolutely. At the very minimum turn on the compilers optimizer at a reasonable level (like `-O2` or `-O3` for `g++` or `clang++` or `/O2` for `msvc`). You may also want to enable Link Time Optimization (that would be `-flto`).

Comment: @JesperJuhl Isn’t this in base 2? I thought 1 MB = 10^6 bytes in base 10.

Comment: Is it enough for me to use Buffer+4 or should I also make the buffer a non-multiple of 8 by adding some offset to get the unaligned behavior?

Comment: @ConventionalProgrammer 2^10 = 1024, so that became a kilobyte.  A megabyte is 2^20, so 1,048,576 bytes

Comment: Strictly speaking 1000000 bytes is 1MB, and 1048576 is 1MiB, but everyone in computing calls the latter 1MB, so I assume that's what the article meant. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabyte

Comment: Side note: Don't use `std::high_resolution_clock` - you don't know what you'll get. cppreference.com [explains it nicely](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock) (read the note).

Comment: @JesperJuhl that note has been edited. In the past it was rather clear, now it is somewhat meh. "Howard Hinnant, who claims to have introduced high_resolution_clock to the language," huh?!? Is there any doubt who introduced it? The rest is actually the same as before just in a very roundabout way and much less clear :/

Comment: The IBM article explains why PowerPC is so slow: *What happened? Because modern PowerPC processors lack hardware support for unaligned floating-point access, the processor throws an exception for each unaligned access. The operating system catches this exception and performs the alignment in software* .  By contrast, x86 doesn't fault on misalignment, and only has penalties when spanning a cache-line boundary (or for older AMD, a 32-byte boundary.)  https://travisdowns.github.io/blog/2019/06/11/speed-limits.html

Comment: [How can I accurately benchmark unaligned access speed on x86\_64?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45128763) has the details on actual misalignment cost on modern x86, which is presumably what you're using.  Also related: [Can modern x86 hardware not store a single byte to memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46721075) / [Are there any modern CPUs where a cached byte store is actually slower than a word store?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54217528) re: byte load/store and unaligned load/store

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you for pointing this. What I was wondering the most is the truth of my test case. I am merely changing the first access addresses, e.g. I am using `Buffer` for alignment access and `Buffer+4` for unalignment access. Is this a true approach to differ these cases?

Comment: `uint64_t Buffer[bufferSize];` makes a buffer of 64-bit elements.  `Buffer+4` in C++ uses C++ pointer math, not assembly.  It advances the pointer by 4 `uint64_t` elements, not 4 bytes.  You need to cast to `char*` to do pointer math.  (And casting back to a misaligned `uint64_t*` would be undefined behaviour.  [Why does unaligned access to mmap'ed memory sometimes segfault on AMD64?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47510783) .  With GCC / clang, you can use `typedef uint64_t unaligned_u64 __attribute__((aligned(1),may_alias))`.

Comment: You probably want to stop the compiler from auto-vectorizing, like `-O3 -fno-tree-vectorize`

Comment: @PeterCordes ++ I also wonder operations on a buffer like this -> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] and like this -> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12] (assume each element is 1 byte) differ in performance at all. For instance, if the access is done by 4-byte granularity, the former buffer requires 3 fetches (4+4+1) and the latter requires 3 fetches (4+4+4) as well, if the former is padded up to 12 bytes, what is the difference? I can't understand how the padding improves performance (or does any good at all) apart from requirements of specific hardware on specific boundaries.

Comment: On x86, no difference.  On many non-x86 CPUs, byte stores are somewhat slower to commit to cache since it doesn't write all the bytes covered by an ECC granule.  [Are there any modern CPUs where a cached byte store is actually slower than a word store?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54217528) - but many CPUs use 8-byte ECC granules so a single 4-byte store isn't any better.  (But three contiguous aligned 4-byte stores will allow one pair to coalesce into one 8-byte commit to cache, and one RMW.  That would also happen with a 9-byte buffer aligned by 8.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Speaking for PowerPC, I get that accessing at odd multiples of memory may affect performance because of the extra shifting and combining operations done on the data, along with making OS software do the work for aligning the data for floating point numbers. However, the padding seems odd to me for performance improvement (I may be totally wrong, I have just read lots of SO answers and they are mainly talking in the context of cache misses etc. rather than examplifying a particular scenario for better acknowledgment).

Comment: What padding?  You mean for alignment?  Often no actual padding is required, unless you have odd amounts of small elements to store along with your larger elements. 
 Aligned data avoids cache-line and page splits for any element of an array, so does help some especially on older Intel where page-splits were even more expensive than on Skylake and later.  With wider SIMD vectors like 32 or especially 64-byte, every (other) vector is a cache-line split.  That can slow down AVX-512 significantly.

Comment: Also noteworthy that `*data64++ = -*data64;` is UB before c++17 (I only notice because of a clang-diagnostic).

Comment: Also noteworthy: Visual Studio's memory protection mechanisms complain about memory corruption. The unaligned read reads 4 bytes past the end of the allocated array, you need to allocate an extra element, `bufferSize+1`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Indeed, I was talking about padding for alignment. "...unless you have odd amounts of small elements to store along with your larger elements.", why the padding is required in this case? Is it because of possible cache-line and page splits that you have mentioned about? As far as I understood, this is the case for older CPU's. So, does aligning the data for the case of "having odd amounts of small elements to store along with your larger elements" using an x86 Ryzen 5600X processor still a performance boost? I can be counted as a newbie in the field, sorry If I misunderstand smth.

Comment: Funny, the VS optimized build is 5-7 times faster *with the 4 byte alignment,* on a Core i7.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: Note earlier comments: `Buffer + 4` isn't misaligned.  The second pass over the uninitialized array might have given the CPU time to get up to max turbo.  And/or the data was hot in L3 (or maybe L2 cache depending on which model of i7).  But not page faults: on Windows when allocating a big stack array like this, you can only grow the stack one page at a time, so it has to loop touching each page.  But only one cache-line per page so it doesn't prime the cache.  Although if the kernel has to zero the pages on the fly in the page-fault handler, they'd also be hot.

Comment: @PeterCordes Ah -- I cast to byte ptr but I `new`d, so the memory is probably over-aligned. Although, that does not make sense (+4 still un-aligns then.) Gonna re-check.

Comment: @ConventionalProgrammer: Memory you allocate is normally aligned by at least 16, or for `malloc`/`new` itself, it's getting memory from the OS as aligned 4K pages.  It doesn't take any padding to store an aligned array of `double` or `uint64_t` elements.  Unless you have say `struct { char a,b,c; uint64_t arr[1024]; };` then you need 5 bytes of padding for the first `uint64_t` to be aligned.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: Ok.  Misaligned loads / stores aren't a big deal on any i7, so it's just warm-up effects from being the second vs. first run, either cache, CPU frequency, or both. ([Idiomatic way of performance evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60291987)).  Probably it auto-vectorizes with SSE2 or AVX2 `vpsubq` to do 16 or 32 bytes at once, so L2 vs. L3 or DRAM bandwidth is a big deal.  (Unlike with unoptimized scalar code in a debug build, where the bottleneck is store/reload latency of a loop variable, giving plenty of time for HW prefetch to keep up.)

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: Or the array accesses optimize away entirely after inlining `Munge64` since the results aren't used.  And the second empty timed region is a lot faster than the first because of warm-up effects like I-cache.

Comment: @PeterCordes So we can safely ignore alignment on i7 but should keep the cache warm in January :-)

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: Mostly yes. Alignment does help with SIMD when data's hot in L1d cache, otherwise L2 bandwidth limits are mostly sufficient for the CPU to hide the extra latency of doing extra accesses to L1d on cache-line splits. Of course *in C++* it's undefined behaviour to even create a misaligned `uint64_t*`, let alone dereference it.  (Use `memcpy` to do unaligned loads/stores safely, also strict-aliasing safe.) And compilers (at least GCC) will break code with alignment UB: [Why does unaligned access to mmap'ed memory sometimes segfault on AMD64?](//stackoverflow.com/q/47510783)

Comment: @PeterCordes So you say that the arrays I allocate on the main stack are already aligned, and it is also the case for the heap with `new`, right? For the `struct { char a,b,c; uint64_t arr[1024]; }; ` case, what if I do not pad the  `char ` attributes? Won't the program be less susceptible to cache misses in this case since the padding means "useless" bytes in the cache? e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20882083/20291711

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: IIRC, looping over a 32-byte aligned array with AVX2 tends to have better DRAM bandwidth by a couple percent on modern Intel, so there is an effect.  (vs. 512-bit vectors slowing down by maybe 15% when not aligned by 64.)

Comment: @ConventionalProgrammer: Yes, packed structs would make your data denser, potentially reducing cache footprint for your whole program, hopefully increasing hit rate.  But most of the time, you don't actually need to waste space on padding to get alignment.  That struct is an example of a rare bad case that you should try to avoid.  An array and 3 separate `char` local variables not part of a struct would let the compiler pack find space for them somewhere. x86-64 calling conventions already require 16-byte stack alignment.

Comment: @PeterCordes I wondered about the UB. The unaligned access is only UB if the hardware makes it so, isn't it? (Which implies a double or 64 bit int can happily sit unaligned on a core i7, as it looks). The aliasing issue is different; but re-creating the array 4 bytes off with placement new should placate the language lawyers.

Comment: *The unaligned access is only UB if the hardware makes it so, isn't it?* - no, I linked [Why does unaligned access to mmap'ed memory sometimes segfault on AMD64?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47510783) precisely because it's a counter-example to that common misconception.  (And links a couple blog articles with other cases, IIRC one involving breakage other than an alignment fault on a 16-byte SSE load)

Comment: @Peter Is padding or not padding that struct the better case? the SO answer I have just shared states that padding the struct is worse because it takes up memory in the cache and increases the cache misses.

Comment: @ConventionalProgrammer: Obviously it's better to arrange your structs so they don't waste space on padding, if you're using a struct at all.  Like in the answer you linked.     Related: [How do I organize members in a struct to waste the least space on alignment?](//stackoverflow.com/q/56761591) - same advice, with some mention of exceptions to the rule: grouping for locality can make sense for some use-cases in big structs, even if it means some padding.
In *rare* cases, it can make sense to use `__attribute__((packed))` to have misaligned members, but that's separate from avoiding padding.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the (repeated) pointer, interesting read.

Comment: @PeterCordes I have a final question. If I have a buffer like -> [char, int , int , double] (for simplicity consider there is a cache-line boundary some where between the char and first int) and want to access one of the integers, if I do not pad the char, don't I increase the chances that I come across a boundary? In this case, I will be also increasing the chances that CPU will fetch the int data in 2 operations rather than 1 since the actual physical locations of different cache-lines separated by boundaries are different, is it right?

Comment: You mean an array of `struct {char c; int i[2]; double d; };`, with or without `__attribute__((packed))`?  Yes, the packed version will have misaligned `int` variables so some of them will span cache-line boundaries.  The normal version, on x86-64 with the System V ABI at least, will have 3 bytes of padding after the `char`, and 4 bytes of padding after the second `int` because `alignof(double) = 8`. And the whole struct will have `alignof(T) = 8`, `sizeof(T) = 24`.  So there can be a cache-line boundary between the two `int`s, but not inside one of them. Draw an array on paper or ASCII art...

Comment: You keep saying "if I don't pad" like that padding was something you had to do manually.  The default is to align every object by at least the `alignof()` for its type.  Using packed structs is the non-standard thing that some compilers have extensions to allow.  (Which makes it unsafe to take a pointer to the struct member if it won't be sufficiently aligned for a normal `int*`.)