# Kind of polymorphism in C

Tags: c, polymorphism

I'm writing a C program in which I define two types:

```
typedef struct {

    uint8_t array[32];
    /* struct A's members */
    ...

} A;

typedef struct {

    uint8_t array[32];
    /* struct B's members, different from A's */
    ...

} B;
```

Now I would like to build a data structure which is capable of managing both types without having to write one for type A and one for type B, assuming that both have a uint8_t [32] as their first member.

I read how to implement a sort of polymorphism in C [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524033/how-can-i-simulate-oo-style-polymorphism-in-c) and I also read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281045/do-class-struct-members-always-get-created-in-memory-in-the-order-they-were-decl) that the order of struct members is guaranteed to be kept by the compiler as written by the programmer.

I came up with the following idea, what if I define the following structure:

```
typedef struct {
    uint8_t array[32];
} Element;
```

and define a data structure which only deals with data that have type Element? Would it be safe to do something like:

```
void f(Element * e){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 32; i++) do_something(e->array[i]);
}

...

A a;
B b;
...
f(((Element *)&a));
...
f(((Element *)&b));
```

At a first glance it looks unclean, but I was wondering whether there are any guarantees that it will not break?

Comment: Is there some reason you're not using C++, if what you want is a polymorphic structure? The expression "use the right tool for the job" comes to mind.

Comment: What's the signature of `do_something()`? Is it limited to accessing only one byte or the array?

Comment: @EricLippert You're right, but I've never used C++ before and this code is part of a project I started long ago using C without having a clear idea of the long term problems I would have had to address.

Comment: @Arun: it's a placeholder I used in this example to mean a generic function that will access the array a byte at a time.

Comment: Why not `A` and `B` have `Element` directly as their first member?

Comment: @Arun: yeah, that's definitely a possibility. But then my data structure holding (Element *) kind of objects would not hold pointers to As and Bs but only to their inner member Element. I would also like to understand what is wrong with the solution I proposed.

Comment: Oh no, there is nothing wrong in your proposal. That would work fine. It is more about understanding your goal and compare to other possibilities.

Comment: You should be fine with your approach as long as you don't overflow `array`. Another thing is that you don't really need to define `Element` because `(uint8_t*)` &a also works.

Comment: This is commonly used in Linux source for e.g. linked lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `array` is always the first in your struct, you can simply access it by casting pointers. There is no need for a struct `Element`. You data structure can store void pointers.

```
typedef struct {
    char array[32];
} A;

typedef struct {
    void* elements;
    size_t elementSize;
    size_t num;
} Vector;

char* getArrayPtr(Vector* v, int i) {
    return (char*)(v->elements) + v->elementSize*i;
}

int main()
{
    A* pa = malloc(10*sizeof(A));
    pa[3].array[0] = 's';
    Vector v;
    v.elements = pa;
    v.num = 10;
    v.elementSize = sizeof(A);
    printf("%s\n", getArrayPtr(&v, 3));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

but why not have a function that works with the array directly 

`void f(uint8_t array[32]){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 32; i++) do_something(array[i]);
}`

and call it like this

`f(a.array)
f(b.array)`

polymorphism makes sense when you want to kepp 
a and b in a container of some sorts 
and you want to iterate over them but you dont want to care that they are different types.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was not clear enough in my question. I need a data structure which serves as a container for any kind of type which has a uint8_t [32] array as its first member. The data structure I propose will store its elements as (Element *) kind of objects.

Comment: Seems to me that what you are trying to do is use C but still keep some c++ type safenes... Since this is C you could store your objects as void* and since you know that they start with uint8_t array[32] cast to that ... or you could access the memory directly ... nobody will mind or care ... in the end it's only memory

Comment: yeah, that's the point, am I guaranteed that accessing `((Element *)&a)->array` will always be the same as accessing `a.array`?

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine if you, you know, don't make any mistakes. A pointer to the `A` struct can be cast to a pointer to the `element` struct, and so long as they have a common prefix, access to the common members will work just fine.

A pointer to the `A` struct, which is then cast to a pointer to the `element` struct can also be cast back to a pointer to the `A` struct without any problems. If `element` struct was not originally an `A` struct, then casting the pointer back to `A` will be undefined behavior. And this you will need to manage manually.

One gotcha (that I've run into) is, gcc will also allow you to cast the `struct` back and forth (not just *pointer to* struct) and this is not supported by the C standard. It will appear to work fine until your (my) friend tries to port the code to a different compiler (suncc) at which point it will break. Or rather, it won't even compile.

Comment: I don't think you did. Upvoting to make up for it :)

Comment: Thanks. I almost gave myself a bald patch from scratching my head! :P